# Why is the file being emptied during input/output redirection to the same file?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

This might look like a very simple question but I haven't been able to come up with a proper explanation so far. Say I use `tr` to transform some random text(it can be any program) and want to output the result into the original file.

```
a@MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads$ cat test_file 
this is a sample text
a@MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads$ tr 't' 'T' <test_file >test_file 
a@MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads$ cat test_file #prints nothing
```

Is there any specific rule/thing that tells us we can't be redirecting both input and output to the same file at the same time? I obviously know that I could have redirected the output into the new file and then copied the result but I am very curious about this behavior.

**P.S** I have been using a Macbook, but this shouldn't matter in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>test_file
```

Truncates the file. then you read a blank file and write nothing back to it.

Use `sponge` if you don't want to create a new file.

```
tr 't' 'T' <test_file | sponge test_file
```

There is also a nice answer at superuser addressing this question: [Why does redirecting the output of a file to itself produce a blank file?](https://superuser.com/questions/597244/why-does-redirecting-the-output-of-a-file-to-itself-produce-a-blank-file)

<sub>PS: I Supposed you are running Ubuntu on a mac.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I just have one more question. Does the redirection order matter in this case? Or it is just how bash operates? (it always opens stdout before stdin?)

Comment: Yes, the order matters, but the shell has to setup the file IO *before* it launches the command.

Comment: Remember, if the output from the command is empty will empty the file.